# Data for UITableView gets changed

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm trying to create a Settings icon for the rightBarButtonItem for my UINavigationController.  In my application:DidFinishLaunching, I create the button, and set it

```
//pseudo code for applicationdidfinish launching

HomeController *home = [[HomeController alloc] init]; // root view of my UINavigationController
home.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingsBarButtonItem;
[settingsButton addTarget:self action:@selector(settingsPressed:) forControlEvents:UIcontrolEventTouchUpInside]; // i used a button for the barbuttonitem to not get the bar button item border
```

than in settingsPressed:

```
SettingsController* settings = [[SettingsController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsController" bundle:nil];
    UINavigationController* popoverNav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:settings];
    [settings release];
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:popoverNav];
    [popoverNav release];
    // show settings
    if ([popover isPopoverVisible]) {
        [popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    } else {
        [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:bbiSettings permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
```

in SettingsController, in viewDidLoad:

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"one", @"two", @"three", nil];
self.DataArray = array; // (nonatomic, retain)
[array release];
```

I do not show this array right away.  Like the iPhone Settings app, when they click on one of the cells in my Grouped Table, it opens up a new UITableView.  So in that UITableView, in the tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: method, I

```
return [self.DataArray count];
```

However, it is here that my app crashes.  When I look at my array, I now have random stuff in there, like vl.proj sometimes, UIViews, etc.  I do not know why this array gets changed.  I do not know if it's because I'm calling the popover from the applicaionDelegate which I normally do not do and that is the problem, or if there is something else wrong.  Thanks.

Comment: what property set to DataArray variable

Comment: @pawan.mangal Nonatomic, retain

Comment: it gets changed cuz its released somewhere, your pointer is pointing to a new object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSArray arrayWithObjects:] returns an autoreleased array. So you don't have to release it manually. You can just remove the line [array release]; in viewDidLoad and everything should work fine.